# What is difference between LP and ALP series of HM628128 SRAM?

Tags: integrated-circuit, design, datasheet

I ordered HM628128**ALP**-10 on aliexpress, got instead HM628128**LP**-8.

When I checked datasheets from internet, it look like -8 is little faster then -10 and LP version takes little more current that ALP to feed inputs (like 2uA instead of 1uA) - not that it matters for me, as I just want build variant of SAP-1 computer with "little more" RAM and some exra features, but it is hobby project and would run on some small frequecy, so all LEDs displaying registers would be visible blinking, not just dimmed lit.

It just catched my interest, but I could not found anything about what the **LP** and **ALP** means - I suspect, that it is something like different derivate families in 74xxx series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series#7400_series_derivative_families , but could not found any similar good reference for it.

Can somebody explain or point me, what the difference actually means?

Comment: if it were laundry detergent, the "A" version might be interpreted as "new-and-improved".

Comment: Have you compared the datasheets? Or should we do that for you?

Comment: As you can see, I tried, and found that -8 is faster (which is "good") and have little larger input currrent (which is "bad"), but nothing substantial for me. But those datasheets (which I found) do tell nothing about LP/ALP and I am curious, what that generally means (not exactly for this one memory, but rather something like "this is newer technology based on X, this have Y advantages, that have Z advatages and typically is better for W applications" and/or "LP is shortcut for this and ALP is shortcut for that, so you can google it" as LP/ALP are too short and I found only unrelevant results